# Libreswan Testbed in VirtualBox

Tags: centos, redhat, ipsec, libreswan

I'm currently working to create a testbed in VirtualBox for two VMs with an isolated opportunistic IPSec network with LibreSwan. All services are coming up fine, but network traffic between the two VMs doesn't seem to actually be encrypted. If I should post this in another Exchange website, please let me know!

I'm following instructions as listed on the libreswan website for opportunistic encryption:

https://libreswan.org/wiki/HOWTO:_Opportunistic_IPsec#Authentication

Here's my relevant configuration:

**Vagrantfile**:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  # Common configuration
  config.vm.box = "centos/7"

  # First machine in IPSec network, named "bast"
  config.vm.define "bast" do |bast|
    bast.vm.hostname = "bast"
    bast.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.2"
    bast.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "bast"
    end
  end

  # Second machine in IPSec network, named "kvothe"
  config.vm.define "kvothe" do |kvothe|
    kvothe.vm.hostname = "kvothe"
    kvothe.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.3"
    kvothe.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.name = "kvothe"
    end
  end

end
```

...and on each machine:

**ipsec.conf**

```
config setup
    protostack=netkey
    #plutodebug="all"
    logfile=/var/log/pluto.log

include /etc/ipsec.d/*.conf
```

**/etc/ipsec.d/oe-certificate.conf**

```
conn private
        # IPsec mandatory
        rightrsasigkey=%cert
        rightauth=rsasig
        right=%opportunisticgroup
        rightca=%same
        left=%defaultroute
        leftauth=rsasig
        leftcert=myhostname
        leftid=%fromcert
        narrowing=yes
        type=tunnel
        ikev2=insist
        auto=ondemand
        # tune remaining options to taste - fail fast to prevent packet loss to the app
        negotiationshunt=hold
        failureshunt=drop
        # 0 means infinite tries
        keyingtries=0
        retransmit-timeout=3s
```

**/etc/ipsec.d/policies/private**

```
192.168.50.0/24
```

I've also verified that `/etc/ipsec.d/policies/{private-or-clear,clear,block,clear-or-private` are all blank, and that there are no other `*.conf` files in `/etc/ipsec.d/` other than `oe-certificate.conf`.

When I execute `ping -I eth1 192.168.50.3` (the private VirtualBox subnet I'm utilizing runs on `eth1` inside the VM) from 192.168.50.2, there's no output from `ipsec whack --trafficstatus`, and the output of `ipsec whack --shuntstatus` is:

```
000 Bare Shunt list:
000
```

Let me know if having the output of `/var/log/pluto.log` and/or `ipsec status` would help - everything seemed clean in those files.

My best guess so far is that there's something funky with the NAT-ing of the VirtualBox network, and that libreswan isn't picking up that the connection is supposed to be encrypted.

I don't have `iptables`, `firewalld` or SELinux enabled.

Thanks in advance!